# How to group cards by column rather than row

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have code like:

```
<div className="row">
  {data.map(datum => <Card field={datum.field} />)}
</div>
```

where `Card` is a variable-height component with `className="col-lg-3"`. This makes rows of cards with whitespace under the shorter cards so that the next row is vertically aligned:

```
Aaa|Bbb|Ccc
aaa|   |ccc
   |   |ccc
Ddd|Eee|Fff
ddd|eee|   
...
```

I want to remove the whitespace. How? The above should instead look like:

```
Aaa|Bbb|Ccc
aaa|Eee|ccc
Ddd|eee|ccc
...
```

I could put something like

```
div className="row">
  <div className="col-lg-3">
    {data1.map(datum => <Card field={datum.field} />) /* where data1 is the first quarter of data */}
  </div>
  {/* same for the remaining data */}
```

... but that looks awful. Among other things, I'd like to keep the cards in the same order as `data`, as sorted from top to bottom; which would be very difficult to do from here. Is there a cleaner solution?

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-dhawan-k45k0b?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Are you concerned about total column height? In other words, are you trying to get the columns to be roughly uniform in height, or are you simply distributing the data by quantity?

Comment: it could be done as a table with 3 cells per row, but i dont it is possible with divs

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a quantitatively uniform column distribution (disregarding final column height), you can just modify your loop to do that. If you want the cards to fit into a minimal-height grid, that becomes a "masonry" problem and gets much more complex.

Start by determining which column each datum belongs to:

```
const getCol = (index) => {
  // add 3 to allow division by 3 and get the remainder
  // add 1 to make column number more intuitive in the markup
  return ((index + 3) % 3) + 1;
};
```

Then check that in your loop:

```
<div className="row">
    <div className='col'>
        {data.map((datum, i) => (
            <>
                {getCol(i) === 1 &&
                    <Card field={datum.field}/>
                }
            </>
        ))}
    </div>

    <div className='col'>
        {data.map((datum, i) => (
            <>
                {getCol(i) === 2 &&
                    <Card field={datum.field}/>
                }
            </>
        ))}
    </div>

    <div className='col'>
        {data.map((datum, i) => (
            <>
                {getCol(i) === 3 &&
                    <Card field={datum.field}/>
                }
            </>
        ))}
    </div>
</div>
```

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-cache-8hgidf?file=/src/App.js)

Of course you could split your array in advance and render the individual sub-arrays in their respective columns as well.